# C++ - unpacking a #defined list of integers into a

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#define ROTATIONS 135, 270, 0,0 , 315, 135

    std::vector<float_t> rotations_vector;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        rotations_vector.push_back(ROTATIONS[i]);
    }
```

As you can see, I want to unload this sequence of DEFINED integers into a vector. However, ROTATIONS cannot be indexed like an array.

It is not an option to change the definition of ROTATIONS. I must unpack it into a vector.

Comment: Please don't use macros for such things (or *at all*, when possible).

Answer (score 2):

Simply place the macro inside an initializer list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define ROTATIONS 135, 270, 0,0 , 315, 135

int main(){
    std::vector<float> rotations_vector = {ROTATIONS};

    for (const auto& r : rotations_vector){
        std::cout << r << ' ';
    }
}
```

The line `std::vector<float> rotations_vector = {ROTATIONS};` will be expanded to `std::vector<float> rotations_vector = {135, 270, 0,0 , 315, 135};`.

Output:

> `135 270 0 0 315 135`

Answer (score 2):

For the love of Bjarne, don't do such things. It's possible, but it's also a great way to make code unreadable.

To answer the question, you have to initialize using the vector with those values, not copy (provided that you use C++11):

```
std::vector<float> rotations_vector = {ROTATIONS};
```

Or before C++11 you could create temporary array and copy from that:

```
float array[] = {ROTATIONS};
std::vector<float> rotations_vector(array, array + (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the constructor taking a list of integers:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#define ROTATIONS 135, 270, 0,0 , 315, 135

int main() {
    std::vector<float> rotations_vector{ ROTATIONS };
    for (const auto& r : rotations_vector) std::cout << r << " ";

}
```